# Was Mary a prostitute in Queensrÿche's "Operation: Mindcrime"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, prog-metal, concept-album, rock-opera

[Queensrÿche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queensr%C3%BFche) in 1988 gave us the rock opera [*Operation: Mindcrime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation%3A_Mindcrime).

It tells the tale of Nikki who succumbs to the underworld of crime.
We learn of his love of a nun, Sister Mary, who later gets killed.  The [lyrics](https://genius.com/Queensryche-spreading-the-disease-lyrics) of "Spreading The Disease" speak of prostitution.  So I wonder if she was the prostitute.

The underworld boss instructs Nikki to kill her, making me think she is a loose end, possibly already having had untoward relations with the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are first introduced to Mary in Track 06: Spreading the Disease.

The lyrics of this track identify a new character "she", with a backstory as a sex worker:

> *She always brings me what I need
>
> Without I beg and sweat and bleed
>
> When we're alone at night
>
> Waiting for the call
>
> She feeds my skin*
>
> *Sixteen and on the run from home
>
> Found a job in Times Square
>
> Working Live S&M shows
>
> Twenty-five bucks (a fuck)
>
> And John's a happy man
>
> She wipes the filth away
>
> And it's back on the streets again*
>
> ...

Later in this track, "she" becomes "Sister Mary":

> ...
>
> *Father William saved her from the streets
>
> She drank the lifeblood from the saviour's feet
>
> **She's Sister Mary now**, eyes as cold as ice
>
> He takes her once a week
>
> On the alter like a sacrifice*
>
> ...

---

If you need any further evidence, in Track 08: Suite Sister Mary, this character is described (in rather unflattering terms):

> ...
>
> *Mary, Mary just a whore for the underground
>
> They made you pay in guilt for your salvation
>
> Thought you had them fooled? Now they've sent me for you
>
> You know too much for your own good*
> ...

---

It's quite unambiguous if you read the lyrics.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  The lyrics of the song Spreading the Disease make this fairly clear and 
Chris Degarmo said of the song in a track by track breakdown:

> Geoff Tate does a vocal rap about the indoctrination process, and the songs >brings in the character of Mary who is a former prostitute.

source: http://www.users.totalise.co.uk/~bigoleg/queensryche/om/features/om_inhis.html

Comment: Hi aceshigh, can you please post relent parts here along with a summary in case the link no longer works one day?

Comment: This is not a reliable source; it is a fanboy website from the early-mid 90's.